# Convert Census shapefile to SVG while keeping internal data?

Tags: python, svg, shapefile

I am very new to GIS so I not sure how difficult this may be. I found a tutorial on how to make a choropleth using Python tools. I want to follow it but use my own data and map. However the tutorial uses a US map SVG file and I need to use a CA zipcode map. The only map that I have found is a shapefile from the US Census. I have tried using kartograph.py to convert it to SVG, but it loses the zipcodes within the file when I do so. This makes it useless as it's then just a shape without the metadata I need. How can I convert the file to SVG and keep each path id'ed as the appropriate zipcode.

I am trying to follow this tutorial [here](http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/). That should give you an idea of what I am trying to do, only I don't have a SVG formatted map.

I have seen references to javascript utilities. I have never used Javascript but suppose I could use something simple.
I suspect I may need to involve the associated dbf file, but don't know how to begin with that.

Comment: What format is your data in?  There are various js libraries that can directly create a map for you in very few lines of code, but it matters if your data is in geoJSON, topoJSON, ...

Comment: It's an ESRI shapefile. It comes as a package with a couple of files.
tl_2010_06_zcta510.dbf

tl_2010_06_zcta510.prj

tl_2010_06_zcta510.shp

tl_2010_06_zcta510.shp.xml

tl_2010_06_zcta510.shx

Comment: can you provide links to the shape file you downloaded?

Comment: Here is a link to the zipfile from the Census https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1x6nYLSpE9rODZPSS1QMmZDR2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This question is answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66041/how-to-convert-shapefile-to-svg-keeping-internal-data

Comment: I saw that answer. As mentioned, Kartograph didn't work for me for whatever reason.